# Iterating through a string with spaces

Tags: ruby

I have a string: `results = "123 456 "`

I would like to iterate through the string and print: "1,2,3, ,4,5,6, "

This is my code thus far:

```
results.each do |k|
  print k, ","
end
```

I have also tried using `each_char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
results.split('').join(',')
# => "1,2,3, ,4,5,6, "
```

Comment: @Bruno The answer didn't state `.each`. Why do you want to iterate again? You're done after the `.join`.

Comment: @MarekLipka maybe you should add a `print`

Comment: @Stefan I think the OP already knows what to do with generated string.

Comment: Sorry I realized I added a .delete(' ') prior to my function. your code works. Thanks! Please delete these comments if you can. Thanks. @MarekLipka

Comment: `split` is definitely the way to go. No need to use an explicit iterator for this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
results.each_char.map
# => ["1", "2", "3", " ", "4", "5", "6", " "]
```

Or, if you want a string as output:

```
result.each_char.map.join(',')
# => "1,2,3, ,4,5,6, "
```

Answer (score 1):

`each_char` works for me:

```
results = "123 456 "
results.each_char do |char|
  print "#{char},"
end
```

Output:

```
1,2,3, ,4,5,6, ,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"123 456 ".gsub(/(?<!\A)(?!\z)/, ",")
# => "1,2,3, ,4,5,6, "
```